# jQuery - Flickr doesn't recognise when text has been entered

Tags: jquery, flickr

I'm using https://www.flickr.com/photos/organize/?start_tab=XXX to batch edit photos. I have the following jQuery which I run in the console, populating the field. It does this fine.

```
jQuery(".together_description").each(function() {
    var myInput = jQuery(this).val();
    jQuery(this).trigger("click");
    jQuery(this).focus();
    jQuery(this).val(myInput + ' courtesy of XXX');
});
```

However, the submit button is not active. It's only active once I click into a field and enter a space/character. Upon saving, only the field I entered text in gets saved, none of the others do.

Any advice or would you need more information?

Comment: try triggering 'change' event instead of 'click'

Comment: No luck - it only seems to work/save when you actively click in a box and enter a character (saves just for that field)

Comment: it looks like they do some work when a certain event is triggered. try triggering all the keyboard events in order to find the one that is doing the extra work. https://api.jquery.com/category/events/keyboard-events/

Comment: Ok - seems we are getting somewhere!

Comment: did you try the 3 possible keyboard events? just to clarify, you have to  trigger them like this: jQuery(this).keydown()

Comment: That's right - use all 3 in one go and it seems to work - haven't tried taking one out and doing trial-and-error. Just happy it works so thanks for the tip!   I did set breakpoints in Chrome console but it just seemed a bit overkill to sift through what was specifically happening